# How to fill fill-in forms inside Microsoft Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

Ever had to fill in a form electronically to apply something?

Here is the scenario:

- You open must apply electronically for something
- You download a Microsoft Word document
- You open it and see that the document contains 'greyed-out fields' that you can only replace, write before or after, or double-click and change their default value

I was in that situation a couple of times over the past few years and couldn't find how to write in those fields. I ended up either giving up by printing the document and filling it out manually, or replacing the grey fields with normal text.

Googling and using Microsoft Word help wasn't any helpful as the only search/help result consisted in tutorials explaining how to *create* the fill-in forms.

Any idea how to persuade Word to let me fill-in these fields?

Comment: Did you open the file with macros enabled? If they're not enabled you can't write in those fields.

Comment: Follow-up question: how come none of those tutorials for creating forms in Word include these instructions for actually enabling the forms?!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just cracked the mystery!!!

In Word 2007:

1. Click on the *office logo* (top left hand corner of the Word window)
2. Click on *Word Options*
3. In the *popular* section, check *Show developer tab in the ribbon* (or in the *customize ribbon* section, tick the 'developer' tab under 'main tabs')
4. Now on the ribbon, select the *Developer* tab
5. Click on the *Protect document* icon/button, a new inspector/sidebar should appear on the right side of the screen
6. In the inspector/sidebar, in the **2.** section, check *Allow only this type of editing in the document*, then choose *Filling in forms* in the drop down list immediately below.
7. Press the *Yes, start enforcing protection* button and provide a password when asked.

This is probably one of the greatest (and best hidden!) great feature of Word. Once you set your password, only somebody that knows your password can change what you entered in the grey-out field!

I really wonder why the microsoft office team took so much effort in hidding that great feature!

Hope this helps!

Comment: For those who are using Office:Mac 2011 - you can find this option by going to the "Review" tab and clicking the "Document" button under the "Protection" category and then selecting "Forms" as the protection level.

Comment: On Mac Office 2016 idolize's solution did not work. The `Restrict Permission` already said `No Restrictions` and there was no other option. The only thing I could do was double-click and change the default value.

Comment: @Leo The solution from idolize works for me in Word 2016. The button is now labeled  "Protect" or "Protect Document". Once the inspector opens, you have to tick the "Protect document for:" box before you can select "Forms".

Comment: The password is optional. You don't have to use one if you use case doesn't require it.

Answer (score 23):

For Office 2010:

1. Select File > Protect Document > Restrict Editing

[image]

2. Click "Yes, Start Enforcing Protection" after ensuring "Filling in Forms" is selected as the Editing Restructions. No password is required (it should have been set by the author - it is required to get back in to edit mode).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## For Mac Office 2016

### Setup, if needed

If you don't see a Developer tab, enable it under the menu `Word`, `Preference`, `View`. The field is at the very bottom, on the left:

[image: Mac Office 2016 View Preferences]

### Enable document protection

On the developer tab, select `Protect Form`:[image: Protect Form button on Mac Word 2016]